# Wave effect around circle when clicked using CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to make a wave effect around the circle when it's being clicked.

[Here](http://g.recordit.co/lEhuqjj5tU.gif) is GIF image of what I want to achieve

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A simple google search will give you tons of tutorials.

Comment: Hey friend, I see you are new here. People on this site love to help, but we really don't like it when new visitors ask for handouts. So try to solve the problem yourself and if you get stuck, post a question showing all the work you've put in so far. Then someone will show you exactly what you need to modify and you won't get crazy downvotes. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Use the hover.css framework for a border transition like "ripple out" or "outline out".

Download Hover.css from here (http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/), add it in your html file. And use the class "hvr-ripple-out" on your circle

`<a href="#" class="hvr-ripple-out circle">Ripple Out</a>`